Calculate number of months, with various situations
I need to be able to calculate the number of months someone has been a member, for each year.  The trouble I'm having is that I want the same formula for each year, whether it's the current year, or a past year--this way I can simplify it going forward.  I have tried IF, IFS, IF(AND, and cannot figure it out.  I know DATEDIF will be used but I can't piece it all together with the correct order.
Here is the link to the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hyBfQBYF1TNmVgXammI5vADWFCD2d1eA/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105919111240161574477&rtpof=true&sd=true
If you notice, I have a 'Donations Summary 2023' and a 'Donations Summary 2024', and column K shows the number of months for a member for 2023 and 2024 respectively.  How do I calculate the number of months they've been a member--whether it's partial year or entire year and whether they joined in the current year or previous year?

Can you manually enter the ideal expected numbers for both the years so that it gives a clear picture on whats really expected here?!

Absolutely, great suggestion.  So, the number in Column K for 2023 is correct, so I know that is part of the correct formula, however, I can't figure out how to modify it so it works for 2024 tab.  I have taken column J for Donations Summary 2024' to reflect what the correct answer should be.

Whats the logic on output being 4 for folks whose join date is prior to 2024(assuming you are considering jan,feb,mar,apr months of 2024) but the output is only 1(and not 2) for joinee of 1-Mar-2024 (only mar seems to be considered and not april)?

The logic for it being 4 for join date prior to 2024, is that they have been a member all year, since we are in the 4th month, it should be 4.  For members that joined in March, we don't count March--only April, so the number of months is 1.  If someone became a member in 2/24, the correct number of months should be 2

Added a formula in both the summary tabs for you to test out (highlighted in red)

That seems to have done it!!  Thank you!  Can you walk me through a bit and explain?  There are some  terms/functions that I'm not familiar with and I want to make sure I understand exactly what you did, so I can learn from it.


You may try:
=let(Σ,2024,Λ,L4,ifs(Λ="",,
     and(year(Λ)<Σ,year(now())=Σ),month(now()),
     and(year(Λ)<Σ,year(now())>Σ),12,
     year(Λ)=Σ,datedif(Λ,min(today(),date(Σ,12,31)),"m")))


Instead of repeating the year 2024 & cell C4 multiple times within the formula, I am just assigning them to variable names like Σ and Λ using let function for ease of use...
